# android camera2 api problem with MediaRecorder

Tags: android, size, android-camera2, mediarecorder, surface

I have a strange bug that my CameraDevice.createCaptureSession don't detect the size of my MediaRecorder Surface and abandonating it. If i disable the media recorder the app works normaly.

Source Code

```
        public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {

            SurfaceTexture texture = previewView.getSurfaceTexture();
            texture.setDefaultBufferSize(size.getWidth(), size.getHeight());
            Surface textureSurface = new Surface(texture);


            mCameraDevice = camera;
            mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
            mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
            mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(size.getWidth(), size.getHeight());
            mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(SENSOR_ORIENTATION_DEFAULT_DEGREES);
            mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(textureSurface);

            int rotation = ((Activity)context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            switch (mSensorOrientation) {
                case SENSOR_ORIENTATION_DEFAULT_DEGREES:
                    mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(DEFAULT_ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));
                    break;
                case SENSOR_ORIENTATION_INVERSE_DEGREES:
                    mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(INVERSE_ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));
                    break;
            }

            try {
                mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getVideoFilePath());
                mMediaRecorder.prepare();
                Surface recorderSurface = mMediaRecorder.getSurface();
                List<Surface> list = new ArrayList<>();
                list.add(recorderSurface);
                final CaptureRequest.Builder captureRequest = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD);
                captureRequest.addTarget(recorderSurface);
                mCaptureRequest = captureRequest.build();
                mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(list, captureStateCallback, backgroundHandler);

            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

StackTrace

E/Legacy-CameraDevice-JNI: LegacyCameraDevice_nativeDetectSurfaceDimens: Error while querying surface width No such device (-19).
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: camera background
    Process: me.wesferr.personalorganizer, PID: 1987
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Surface was abandoned
        at android.hardware.camera2.utils.SurfaceUtils.getSurfaceSize(SurfaceUtils.java:89)
        at android.hardware.camera2.params.OutputConfiguration.(OutputConfiguration.java:260)
        at android.hardware.camera2.params.OutputConfiguration.(OutputConfiguration.java:145)
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.createCaptureSession(CameraDeviceImpl.java:520)
        at me.wesferr.personalorganizer.CaptureVideoClass$1.onOpened(CaptureVideoClass.java:133)
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$1.run(CameraDeviceImpl.java:149)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
     Caused by: android.hardware.camera2.legacy.LegacyExceptionUtils$BufferQueueAbandonedException
        at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.LegacyExceptionUtils.throwOnError(LegacyExceptionUtils.java:73)
        at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.LegacyCameraDevice.getSurfaceSize(LegacyCameraDevice.java:606)
        at android.hardware.camera2.utils.SurfaceUtils.getSurfaceSize(SurfaceUtils.java:87)
        at android.hardware.camera2.params.OutputConfiguration.(OutputConfiguration.java:260) 
        at android.hardware.camera2.params.OutputConfiguration.(OutputConfiguration.java:145) 
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.createCaptureSession(CameraDeviceImpl.java:520) 
        at me.wesferr.personalorganizer.CaptureVideoClass$1.onOpened(CaptureVideoClass.java:133) 
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$1.run(CameraDeviceImpl.java:149) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)

Comment: Try preparing your `MediaRecorder` earlier, like in `onCreate`. I think the problem might be that `MediaRecorder`/surface is not ready by the time you query it.

Comment: If that's not the case, it could also be that your device cannot run `MediaRecorder` and Camera simultaneously.

Comment: @HB what information are you going by in regards to "cannot run `MediaRecorder` and Camera simultaneously"?

Comment: @DaveNottage By testing it on multiple devices.